# Static JS file not loading on Dynamic page in nuxtJS

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Script is loading just fine in other pages but not loading on dynamic pages in NuxtJS. My `nuxt.config.js` file reference -

```js
head: {
    script:[
      { src: 'test.min.js' }
    ],
  }
```

**[NB] The `test.min.js` file is in root of `static` directory.**

Dynamic route e.g. `products/_slug/index.vue`

```
GET http://localhost:3000/products/abc-def/test.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Can you please help me resolve this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify an absolute path with something like

```js
/test.min.js

@/test.min.js // or maybe this one

@@/test.min.js // or even this one
```

Comment: `/test.min.js` worked for me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify an absolute path as kissu mentioned and also you can try this:

```
~/test.min.js
```

In many times it works too